# Finding solutions in modulo

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

If I know $x$ modulo m and n, then under what conditions on m,n and p will i necessarily know $x$ modulo p?

My initial guess is only in trivial cases, i.e. p is a multiple of m or n, but i cant seem to figure it out

Comment: Do you know CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: @BillDubuque Nay